# Mark inputText as invalid in Invoke Applications phase

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, error-handling

I am performing some business rule validations in the Invoke Applications phase, and when there is an error, a custom Exception will be thrown. The custom exception is handled in a custom JSF ErrorHandler, where the input component in question will be marked as invalid, FacesMessages created and validation will be failed on the FacesContext.

**Bean**

```
public void performAction() {

    if ("aaa".equals(input)) {
        // custom exception: arg1 - Error Message, arg2 - clientId
        throw new ServiceValidationException("Something went wrong", ":f:input");
    }
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<h:form id="f">
    <p:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.input}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.performAction}"/>
</h:form>
```

**Custom JSF ErrorHandler**

```
@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {

    try {
        Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
        if (unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents.hasNext()) {
            Throwable exception = unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents.next().getContext().getException();
            Throwable rootCause = unwrapRootCause(exception);

            if (rootCause instanceof ServiceValidationException) {

                ServiceValidationException sve = (ServiceValidationException) rootCause;
                JSFComponentUtil.markComponentAsInvalid(sve.getClientId());
                // create FacesMessage here etc
                ...
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error encountered while processing exception, allow default error handling to take over", e);
    }
    // delegate to Omnifaces Ajax exception handler
    super.handle();
}
```

**JSFComponentUtil**

```
public static void markComponentAsInvalid(String componentId) {
    UIComponent component = findComponent(componentId);
    if (component != null && component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
        EditableValueHolder evh = (EditableValueHolder) component;
        if (evh.isValid()) {
            evh.setValid(false);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.debug("component not found or is not instance of EditableValueHolder");
    }
}

public static UIComponent findComponent(String componentId) {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    if (viewRoot != null) {
        return viewRoot.findComponent(componentId);
    }
    LOG.debug("View Root is null, returning null");
    return null;
}
```

**The Problem**
The issue I'm running into is that upon submitting the form via the command button, the page redisplays with the input text field marked as red (expected behavior), however the text that was typed into the field is lost. I want the invalid text entered to remain in the field.

Comment: The "JSF way" is to perform validation using a normal validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In markComponentInvalid, you can try manually setting the component's value:

```
evh.setSubmittedValue("aaa");
evh.setValue("aaa");
```

Of course, instead of hard-coding "aaa" you could add an "input" property to your ServiceValidationClass so that you can pass that value from the action method to the error handler and then to the Util class, e.g.

bean:

```
throw new ServiceValidationClass ("Something went wrong", ":f:input", input);
```

error handler:

```
JSFComponentUtil.markComponentAsInvalid(sve.getClientId(), sve.getInput());
```

etc.

Comment: That's an idea. If there is no other "JSF way" to handle this, I will accept this answer. Thanks!